# C# Missing Assembly Even After Adding Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I have a question why does I can't import anything from other project even after I add the reference. I tried to create a project for learning best practice by following some tutorial. First I create a console app and name it `Prestige Biz` later on I notice that I type a wrong project name and wanted to follow the tutorial, so I rename it to `Prestige.Biz` (I also change the all the namespace in code, folder name, assembly name, and default namespace to `Prestige.Biz`). After that I create new project for testing named `Prestige.BizTest` and add reference in testing project to the console app. I can see the reference added, the path to code, and the code in the reference (by double clicking it) all right and good. Then I tried to create an object from `Prestige.Biz` but I can't. I can't even add `using Prestige.Biz` all the suggestion give is `using Prestige.BizTest`. I tried to rebuild everything, reopen the visual studio but nothings work.

I create new project without making typo in project name and it all working fine, but the previous error really bother me. What I did wrong? Am I making a mistke by editing the project designer

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is not useful for you then please don't mark it negative. But I have solve this way.

I was face same issue and solve as below.
If you change project name then you also need to change into project file "Visual C# project file".

Open this file into notepad and change as below highlighted place.

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>your new project name</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>**your new project name**</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

[image: visual c# project file]

Comment: I comment based on my understanding. Please don't that "This answer is not useful". I will remove it from here. If it is not useful.

Comment: Hi, I just check it and it appear the <RootNamespace> and <AssemblyName> value is already converted to the new project name. Maybe the IDE automate it. Still getting the same error. I use visual studio 2017 Enterprise by the way.

Comment: Ok, In my case it was not converted and resolved. I need to check your case in VS 2017. I did in VS 2012. I think should be same.